# /var/cache on temporary filesystem

Tags: cache, tmpfs

Due to flash degradation concerns, I would like to lower the amount of unnecessary disk writes on a headless light-duty 24/7 system, as much as sensible. In case it matters this is a Debian-flavored system, but I think the issue might be of relevance for a wider audience.

In order to achieve this, I am already using **tmpfs** for `/tmp` and `/var/log` in addition to the defaults. At this point, by monitoring idle IO activity with various tools like *fatrace*, I get that after long periods one of the most prominent directories in number of write accesses is `/var/cache`, especially `/var/cache/man` related to *man-db*. Note that I don't have automatic package updates in this system, so I don't get any writes for `/var/cache/apt`, but for others that might be relevant too.

The question is, could it cause any trouble if **tmpfs** would be used for `/var/cache`? On startup I would populate it with data from disk, and possibly *rsync* it back from time to time.

Of course the elevated RAM usage might be an issue on some systems, but it would be interesting to hear your opinions whether it would be problematic for some of the common systems using the cache, to have data absent in the early boot process, or generally be in a slightly outdated state (after a crash for example)?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1030207/on-modern-linux-is-it-safe-or-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-move-all-active-writes-of-th

Comment: Thanks for the link, great suggestions on some other directories that might be written frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty cool idea.  I mount `/var` on a magnetic drive for this reason, but I like this.  Whether this would work is application-specific.

Does `apt` require `/var/cache/apt/` to exist or will it create the directory when needed?  `dpkg -S /var/cache/apt/` tells me this directory is created during package installation.  So if that directory doesn't exist, will `apt` create it?   Will `apt` start to fail?  The answer to those questions lies in `apt`.  You could make this point void by creating a `tmpfs` for `/var/cache/apt`.

While a `tmpfs` for `/var/cache/apt` may work for `apt`, you'll have to repeat the process for all other packages which use `/var/cache/*`.  Some directories on my machine are: `apache2`, `fonts`, `gdm`, `cups`, `man`, `dictionaries-common` `app-info`.  In addition, whenever you install a new package, you'll need to remember to set up any applicable `tmpfs` for that package too.  This might be tough to manage.

Fortunately the filesystem heirarchy standard describes `/var/cache` as:

> Application cache data. Such data are locally generated as a result of time-consuming I/O or calculation. The application must be able to regenerate or restore the data. The cached files can be deleted without loss of data.

So I could be wrong.  Applications may be implemented in a way that subdirectories in `/var/cache` are created if needed because the standard requires them to.  But it's still a risk in case someone isn't compliant with that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the FHS. Hopefully it is called _standard_ for a reason, so I can be confident that at least major packages should respect its instructions. For my specific purposes this might be enough, but it is noted that one must be wary of any other possibly non-conformant software when using this method.